# How to get number of threads supported by CPU which can do hyper-threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, cpu

My AMD CPU has 8 cores and with hyper-threading, can support up to 8 threads.

How do I get the number threads that can be supported by a CPU in python? I know how to get number of cores(see code below) but don't know how to get number of threads.

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

I am using windows 10, python 3.7.

EDIT: `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` is right answer. It includes the effects of hyper-threading.

Comment: There is no limitation for threads? you can raise any number which you like. It depends on what calculation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The answer is already in the question. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` returns the number of CPU threads supported by the CPU and this number includes the effects of hyper-threading.